# CSV to JSON java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to convert csv to json with java(jackson).
I would like not to read a specific column based on column name.

CODE:
        public class CSV2JSON {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File input = new File("input.csv");
    File output = new File("output.json");

    CsvSchema csvSchema = CsvSchema.builder().setUseHeader(true).build();
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

    // Read data from CSV file
    List readAll = csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class).with(csvSchema).readValues(input).readAll();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // Write JSON formated data to output.json file
    mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(output, readAll);

    // Write JSON formated data to stdout
    System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(readAll));
}
```

}

I  don't want to read specific column from csv file.
My csv file.This is a sample with 3 columns and 3 rows.

```
    city,population,area
    Berlin,3500000,891
    Paris,2241346,105
    London,8800000,1572
```

So if i don't want the population column to be read then i should be able to skip population column.

Please Help!.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove unwanted column from schema builder and disable 'failOnUnknownProperty' feature

Comment: can you share any documentation link for doing this?